# Can't debug .cshtml when using local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor

I have a problem regarding all of my Projects when trying to Debug .cshtml files when the application is hosted on a local IIS.

I always get the Message that the symbols aren't loaded:

[image]

Debugging the controller works fine though.

When debugging the application with IIS Express everything works as expected.

Here is how my Application is configured:

[image]

Every help is appreciated, because i am starting to freak out over that problem...

Edit: I am using VS 2015 Enterprise and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

The location path of iis view files are different from your coding path. Create virtual directory in iis and set the path from project folder.